# HTTP 400 on IIS 6.0

Tags: http, iis

I'm trying to create HTTP request to XML service and I'm getting 400 errors from IIS server.

This request WORKS:

```
T 192.168.0.10:52584 -> 193.189.144.141:80 [AP]
  50 4f 53 54 20 2f 73 63    72 69 70 74 73 2f 58 4d    POST /scripts/XM
  4c 5f 49 6e 74 65 72 66    61 63 65 2e 64 6c 6c 20    L_Interface.dll 
  48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 30    0d 0a                      HTTP/1.0..      
###
T 192.168.0.10:52584 -> 193.189.144.141:80 [AP]
  48 6f 73 74 3a 20 77 77    77 31 2e 67 6e 74 2e 6c    Host: www1.gnt.l
  74 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65    6e 74 2d 74 79 70 65 3a    t..Content-type:
  20 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61    74 69 6f 6e 2f 78 2d 77     application/x-w
  77 77 2d 66 6f 72 6d 2d    75 72 6c 65 6e 63 6f 64    ww-form-urlencod
  65 64 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74    65 6e 74 2d 6c 65 6e 67    ed..Content-leng
  74 68 3a 20 37 33 0d 0a    43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 69    th: 73..Connecti
  6f 6e 3a 20 63 6c 6f 73    65 0d 0a 0d 0a 4d 66 63    on: close....Mfc
  49 53 41 50 49 43 6f 6d    6d 61 6e 64 3d 44 65 66    ISAPICommand=Def
  61 75 6c 74 26 55 53 45    52 4e 41 4d 45 3d 73 65    ault&USERNAME=se
  63 72 65 74 26 50 41 53    53 57 4f 52 44 3d 73 65    cret&PASSWORD=se
  63 72 65 74 26 43 48 45    43 4b 3d 73 65 63 72 65    cret&CHECK=secre
  74 26 58 4d 4c 3d 0d 0a    0d 0a                      t&XML=....
```

Although this one DOESN'T WORK:

```
T 192.168.0.10:52592 -> 193.189.144.141:80 [AP]
  50 4f 53 54 20 2f 73 63    72 69 70 74 73 2f 58 4d    POST /scripts/XM
  4c 5f 49 6e 74 65 72 66    61 63 65 2e 64 6c 6c 20    L_Interface.dll 
  48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 30    0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e    HTTP/1.0..Conten
  74 2d 54 79 70 65 3a 20    61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74    t-Type: applicat
  69 6f 6e 2f 78 2d 77 77    77 2d 66 6f 72 6d 2d 75    ion/x-www-form-u
  72 6c 65 6e 63 6f 64 65    64 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65    rlencoded..Conte
  6e 74 2d 4c 65 6e 67 74    68 3a 20 37 32 0d 0a 48    nt-Length: 72..H
  6f 73 74 3a 20 77 77 77    31 2e 67 6e 74 2e 6c 74    ost: www1.gnt.lt
  0d 0a 55 73 65 72 2d 41    67 65 6e 74 3a 20 50 79    ..User-Agent: Py
  74 68 6f 6e 2d 75 72 6c    6c 69 62 2f 31 2e 31 37    thon-urllib/1.17
  0d 0a 0d 0a 58 4d 4c 3d    26 55 53 45 52 4e 41 4d    ....XML=&USERNAM
  45 3d 73 65 63 72 65 74    26 50 41 53 53 57 4f 52    E=secret&PASSWOR
  44 3d 73 65 63 72 65 74    26 4d 66 63 49 53 41 50    D=secret&MfcISAP
  49 43 6f 6d 6d 61 6e 64    3d 44 65 66 61 75 6c 74    ICommand=Default
  26 43 48 45 43 4b 3d 63    68 65 63 6b                &CHECK=check
```

Exact error message:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0.
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET.
Date: Wed, 13 Jul 2011 20:53:07 GMT.
Connection: close.
.
```

Any ideas where's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by changing order of arguments.

Made `MfcISAP=Default` the first argument